# WPF XAML: How to fix "Value cannot be null" with custom RoutedEvent

Tags: wpf, xaml, routed-events

I've define a custom `RoutedEvent` and use it in `EventTrigger`. But VS keep showing error.

Event definition:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Lock
{
    add { AddHandler(LockEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(LockEvent, value); }
}
public static readonly RoutedEvent LockEvent =
    EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Lock", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyControl));
```

Event usage:

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static local:MyControl.LockEvent}">
        <BeginStoryboard/>
    </EventTrigger>
<UserControl.Triggers>
```

The code can be run but there is always a squiggly line under `RoutedEvent="{x:Static local:MyControl.LockEvent}"` and giving error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
```

How can I fix this error? (or how to ignore it without [Suppress XAML Designer errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-errors-warnings?view=vs-2019#suppress-xaml-designer-errors)?)

---

> If I use the RoutedEvent like this: `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyControl.Lock">`, another error occurs:
>
> ```
> The event 'Lock' is not a RoutedEvent.
> ```
>
> And the design view crashed.
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You reference an event like this using xmlnsAlias:ControlType.Event.

And you should add an event, compile then try and reference it.

**Edit:
Let's make this thing actually animate something and end to end it.**

This works for me:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
        <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:UserControl1.Lock">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                          To="Green" 
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                          Duration="0:0:0.5"
                          />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        </UserControl.Triggers>
        <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

and

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public event RoutedEventHandler Lock
        {
            add { AddHandler(LockEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(LockEvent, value); }
        }
        public static readonly RoutedEvent LockEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Lock", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl1));
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(UserControl1.LockEvent);
        RaiseEvent(args);
    }
```

This works whatever platform I target and animates the usercontrol background to green.

Comment: can you try your code on platform x64?

I've copy your code, it's ok. but after switch platform to x64, the error occurred.

Comment: @lymims I  added code to raise the event and an actual animation to the storyboard to prove it works. Which it does, regardless of platform.

Comment: I added a shot of that error. The code works but the error still there, is there any way to remove it?